# tmpfiles.d -- difference between `x` and `X` options?

Tags: tmp

I'm configuring tmp cleanup on CentOS 7. The [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html) for tmpfiles are a little unclear to me when explaining the difference between the `X` and `x` options in `tmp.conf`. The difference according to the docs is that with the `X` option,

> Unlike `x`, this parameter will not exclude the content if path is a directory, but only directory itself.

I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Basically I have a directory which lives in `/tmp` and which I *don't* want to be deleted (including its contents). For this, is it enough to add a line

```
x /tmp/myspecialdir
```

to `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

I also found this very confusing. Here's a quick example. I think x versus X becomes useful if you have a deep tree inside a particular directory and you want to delete some and not all directories.

Here's my exclude.conf:

```
root# cat /etc/tmpfiles.d/exclude.conf 
d /tmp/testdir 0755 root root 1s
x /tmp/testdir/*
```

Now, I create some directories:

```
# mkdir /tmp/testdir/a ; mkdir /tmp/testdir/b; mkdir /tmp/testdir/ab

# ls -lrt /tmp/testdir/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Sep  1 12:55 a
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Sep  1 12:55 b
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Sep  1 12:55 ab
```

Run clean

```
#systemd-tmpfiles --clean exclude.conf
```

Check

```
# ls -lrt /tmp/testdir
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Sep  1 12:55 a
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Sep  1 12:55 b
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Sep  1 12:55 ab
```

Now, if do `X /tmp/testdir/*`, I get the same result. Then, if I have `x /tmp/testdir/b`, then it excludes the 'b' directory from the cleanup.

```
#systemd-tmpfiles --clean exclude.conf

# ls -lrt /tmp/testdir/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Sep  1 12:55 b
```

Also, `X /tmp/testdir/b` shows the same behavior. However, `X /tmp/testdir/` and `x /tmp/testdir` will delete all the sub directories inside `testdir` but will keep `testdir`.

I would suggest to test the settings before you put it in place. I the man page could be little more clearer.